# Parallel Stream in scala

Tags: java, scala

is there any (hopefully out of the box) way to traverse an Scala stream in parallel?

for instance, see this java 8 code:

```
String[] s = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s);
list.parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

this will print all list stream contents in parallel..
however, to my understanding, streams in scala are sequential.

any workarounds for this?

**EDIT:** 
please notice that, streams allows us to process data as they arrive. then, if data is not necessary, remove them from memory.
for instance:

```
"abcd".toStream.filter { x => 
  println(s"1 filter $x")  
   if(x.toInt%2==0) true;else false;
  } //end of first block
  .foreach { x => 
  println(s"2 filter->$x")  
  } //end of second block
```

will output something like this:

1 filter a

1 filter b

2 filter->b

1 filter c

1 filter d

2 filter->d

on the other hand, the below code, will process data in blocks. keeping variables in memory on each transformation:

```
  "abcd".toVector.par.filter { x => 
  println(s"1 filter $x")  
   if(x.toInt%2==0) true;else false;
  } //end of first block
  .foreach { x => 
  println(s"2 filter->$x")  
  } //end of second block
```

output:
1 filter c

1 filter a

1 filter b

1 filter d

2 filter->b

2 filter->d

Comment: In addition to the more informative answers below, here is a one liner doing what you want: `('a' to 'e').par.foreach(println _)`

Comment: @evan.oman I don't think any of the current answers address the question

Answer (score 4):

Many (most?) Scala collections have a `par` method that "returns a parallel implementation of this collection."

From the ScalaDocs:

> For most collection types, this method creates a new parallel collection by copying all the elements. For these collections, `par` takes linear time.

A Scala `Stream[]` has no direct parallel implementation, so you get `ParSeq[]` instead, and since `ParSeq` is a trait, the REPL will instantiate it as a `ParVector`.

```
scala> Stream("a","b","c","d","e").par
res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[String] = ParVector(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Also worth noting is the information elsewhere in the ScalaDocs:

> The higher-order functions passed to certain operations may contain side-effects. Since implementations of bulk operations may not be sequential, this means that side-effects may not be predictable and may produce data-races, deadlocks or invalidation of state if care is not taken. It is up to the programmer to either avoid using side-effects or to use some form of synchronization when accessing mutable data.

So your `foreach(println)` code might have unpredictable/undesirable results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html)

```
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector

val pv = new ParVector[Int]

val pv = Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).par

pv.foreach(x => println(x));
```

Comment: but ParVector does not behave like a jdk8 stream. :c

Answer (score 0):

At the current time I'm aware of two possibilities that might usefully be pursued.

You should be able to use the Java 8 Stream API directly, assuming, of course, that you're running Scala on a JVM.

Alternatively, I think you might investigate Apache Spark. I've only started tinkering with this, but as I interpret it, while a large part of its power derives from sharding work across multiple machines, it nevertheless provides a parallel execution mode even on a single machine. Design-wise, it appears to be a "Streams-on-steroids" thing and seems like it does laziness if your data source allows it. I'll be pursuing this further myself, so any updates will be of interest to me too!